# Applying statsforecast implementation of expanding window cross-validation to multiple time series with varying lengths

Tags: python, time-series, cross-validation, statsforecast

I am looking to assess the accuracy of different classical time series forecasting models by implementing expanding window cross-validation with [statsforecast](https://nixtla.github.io/statsforecast) on a time-series dataset with many unique IDs that have varying temporal lengths that can range between 1 to 48 months. I would like to forecast the next seven months after the ending month of each window and assess the accuracy with some error metric (e.g., sMAPE). There is potentially seasonality and trend in the different time series, so I would like to capture these in the cross-validation process as well. However, I am having difficulty and not fully understanding the different parameters (`step_size`, `n_windows`, `test_size`) in the package's cross-validation function.

Could someone advise me in setting up the right parameters? Is what I'm looking for even feasible with the function provided in the package? How do I decide the best value for `step_size`, `test_size` and `n_windows`?

For reference, my data looks like this:

df =

|  | unique_id | ds | y |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 111111 | 2000-01-01 | 9 |
| 1 | 111111 | 2000-02-01 | 9 |
| 2 | 111111 | 2000-03-01 | 10 |
| 3 | 111111 | 2000-04-01 | 4 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 999999 | 111269 | 2003-10-01 | 32532 |
| 1000000 | 111269 | 2003-11-01 | 0 |
| 1000001 | 111269 | 2003-12-01 | 984214 |

And to be explicit, the history for individual unique_ids can vary (i.e., the length of the time series is unequal between unique_ids.)

I have already instantiated my StatsForecast object with the requisite models:

```
sf = StatsForecast(
    df=df,
    models=[AutoARIMA(season_length=12), AutoETS(error_type='zzz'), Naive()],
    freq='MS',
    n_jobs=-1,
    fallback_model=Naive()
)
```

Then, I call the cross_validation method:

```
results_cv = sf.cross_validation(
    h=7 # Predict each of the future seven months
    step_size=?,
    n_windows=?
)
```

I have tried an assortment of parameter values for step_size and n_windows together, and also just for test_size alone (e.g., 7 because I want to compare the last 7 months of actuals and forecasts in each window), but I'm always left with the following error:

[ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (y,) into shape (z,)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nwPL0.png)

I expect the end result to look similar to the data-frame presented in the statsforecast tutorial:
[screenshot from the GitHub example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cLmPN.png)

[or scroll down to 'crossvaldation_df.head()'](https://nixtla.github.io/statsforecast/examples/getting_started_complete.html#evaluate-the-models-performance)

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem related to using a `step_size` bigger than the series size. You can try filtering out the smaller series or trying to add zeros at the beginning of those.

You can check it with:

```
df.groupby('unique_id').agg({'y': 'count'}).sort_values(by='y')
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Yea! I ended up having to filter out series with length less than the step_size.